# Fourier transform dependent upon a parameter and $L^2$ convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-transforms

Suppose I know the Fourier transform of a function depending upon a parameter, call it $f_\epsilon(x)$, and that I want to know the Fourier transform of a function $f(x)$. Furthermore, suppose I know that $\|f-f_\epsilon\|\rightarrow0$ for $\epsilon \rightarrow0$ in the sense of the $L^2$ norm (or $L^1$). Can I recover the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ by taking the limit of the Fourier transform $\hat f(\omega,\epsilon)$ for  $\epsilon \rightarrow0$?

Comment: Since the Fourier transform defines a unitary transformation between two Hilbert spaces I would say yes.

Comment: Why don't you consider $||f-f_\epsilon ||_1\rightarrow_{\epsilon \to 0} 0$?

Comment: Well yeah, I'll edit the question asking for both.

Comment: @GennaroMarcoDevincenzis: See the answer.

Comment: I 'd wait a little bit more to see if someone has a proof for the $L^2$ norm, then I'll accept it.

Comment: @GennaroMarcoDevincenzis: Have you given it a try?

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $ ||f-f_\epsilon ||_1\rightarrow_{\epsilon \to 0} 0 $ then we have

$$ \Bigg| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{\epsilon} (x) e^{-ixw}dx - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f (x) e^{-ixw}dx  \Bigg| \leq  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f_{\epsilon}(x)-f(x)|dx $$

$$ = ||f-f_\epsilon ||_1 \rightarrow_{\epsilon \to 0}0 .$$